# Swift if statement not working. Clearly a bug, but whats the pattern

Tags: xcode, swift, if-statement

I have the following code fragment in an app. The 'if' statement wasn't properly evaluated. Even though score = -100 and bestScore = 200, the if statement if score < bestScore does not run the code within it. bestScore stays at 200.

If I add a print statement within the if, it suddenly starts working. I tried it in a playground without the print statement and it works fine. I've replace some expressions with 'true' for simplicity.

```
        var bestScore = 200
        var score = 200
        if true {
            if true {
                score = -100
            } 
        }
        if score < bestScore {
            print("Testing") // When this wasn't here it wasn't working
            bestScore = score
            bestMove = move
        }
```

I've seen this sort of strange behavior in Swift before, rarely, but I can't figure out a pattern to explain when this happens. This is with Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a).

Edit: I can no longer reproduce this error with Xcode 6.2 beta 5, so I assume this has been corrected.

Comment: That's clever. You have a bug in your code that you can't explain, and then you post some modified code. Post the original. As long as you don't accept that the bug is in your code, you won't find it.

Comment: Since you haven’t posted anything reproducible, it’s hard for anyone to have anything more to say… do you have an example that doesn’t work, rather than an example that does work but doesn’t in the context of your unpublished project?  I've seen instances where the optimizer does elide code it that it shouldn’t have because it had side-effects, but those have always been reproducible in a short bit of standalone example code you could compile with `swiftc`.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thats the point. The question is, what sort of code patterns could cause the Swift compiler to get confused by the if statement. I have not changed the values of the variables and have not changed the if statement that failed. I indicated the one line who's addition made it work. How could adding a print fix the evaluation of the if statement? I guess I shouldn't ask questions about Apple bugs here. I've tried the same code in Xcode 6.2 beta 5 and its working without the print so I assume this particular compiler scenario has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much like something I experienced.
Though it's not the same situation, it does involve the assignment of a property after a print statement and that did not occur if the print statement wasn't there. Long story short, it was a bug that I sent a report of to apple that is still under investigation.

[Very unusual Xcode compile behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536244/very-unusual-xcode-compile-behaviour)