# Swift Optional binding of NSBundle.pathForResource is returning garbage?

Tags: ios, swift, nsbundle

I am a longtime iOS developer, but just getting started in swift. I'm working on a test program that crops images. I'm making good progress, but have come on something very strange.

I am trying to play a shutter sound when the user crops and image (and saves it to their photo library.

I wrote a function that creates an AVAudioPlayer for my shutter sound. That function gets' called by a lazy stored property, but that detail shouldn't matter.

The function looks like this:

```
func loadShutterSoundPlayer() -> AVAudioPlayer?
{
  let theMainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
  let filename = "Shutter sound"
  let fileType = "mp3"
  if let soundfilePath = theMainBundle.pathForResource(filename, 
    ofType: fileType)
  {
    let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundfilePath)
    return AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
  }
  else
  {
    return nil
  }
}
```

When written with optional binding as above, the `if let soundfilePath` bit thinks it succeeds, and executes the conditional code inside the braces, but the resulting value in soundfilePath is garbage. Sometimes it's random characters, sometimes it's a method name, etc. It's like the memory policy on the NSBundle method pathForResource:ofType: is releasing the object and creating a zombie.

If I rewrite the code to **not** use optional binding, it works as expected:

```
func loadShutterSoundPlayer() -> AVAudioPlayer?
{
  let theMainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
  let filename = "Shutter sound"
  let fileType = "mp3"
  let soundfilePath: String? = theMainBundle.pathForResource(filename, 
    ofType: fileType)
  if soundfilePath != nil
  {
    let fileURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundfilePath!)
    return AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
  }
  else
  {
    return nil
  }
}
```

Am I missing something here? This smells to me like a compiler bug or a bug in the definition of the NSBundle method pathForResource:ofType: that's generating bad ARC code.

Comment: Your codes are corrects in 2 cases.  Maybe it's a XCode bug. What is the version of your XCode?. Try to restart XCode. Or add a NSLog to show the value of your soundFilePath : NSLog("file %@", soundfilePath)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.2, the release version (Build 6C131e). I haven't logged the output of soundFilePath, but I've looked at it in the debugger. It's garbage when I run the optional binding version of the code. Very strange.

Comment: I would also recommend to print the path with println or NSLog. The debugger variables view is sometimes wrong.

Comment: Martin, thanks for weighing in. I had the same thought as I was typing my response to @HoaParis' comment.

Comment: Ok, this is maddening. I put back the code that crashes, put in a println(), and it displays correctly, and the code is now working. It seems it's decided to stop failing now (and yes, I had previously quit Xcode, and even restarted my Mac)

Comment: You can use xcode console to display value of your variables in the memory stack. Type : p fileSoundPath then press enter when xcode pause at the breakpoint.

Comment: That's what I've been doing @HoaParis. The really strange thing is that the problem stopped happening. At Martin's suggestion, I added println() statements to try to look at the value, and haven't seen the problem recur since. This is  weird one.

Comment: Sometimes, `println` hides some compiler bugs.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26536244/3804019